# Windows7 no longer boots after moving hard-disk to other computer

Tags: windows-7, boot, upgrade

A friend asked me to reinstall Windows on a used laptop she got from her previous job, but the BIOS is password-protected and it'd be a hassle to bring it back and ask a techie to remove it.

So I removed the hard-disk, plugged it into my computer, installed W7, and put it back into the laptop. But because of the significant hardware change, W7 refuses to boot.

Does it mean that it's simply not allowed to make serious changes to a computer and expect W7 to boot, or is there a command to run before making changes?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try booting in safe mode? Your question doesn't give us very much information.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using the instructions here http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip on sysrep. It failed with its "Fatal Error" and playing with the Registry didn't solve it, so I just gave up and installed XP.